# Laravel project next to Wordpress project (in public_html folder)

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, laravel, http

I have a **Laravel** project in my **public_html** folder. The domain is for example **domain.com** My .htaccess file (in public_html folder) is like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

There are the following routes:

- api/licenseplate
- api/calendar
- auth/login
- admin/settings
- admin/appointments
- appointment
- ...

So an example of a URL is **http://domain.com/appointment**.

Now I would like to have a wordpress website on domain.com. So when you go to domain.com you see the wordpress website. But I also want to have the urls like /appointment of my laravel project.

What's the easiest and cleanest way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to install wordpress at public_html directory or a sub-directory inside public_html e.g. public_html/wordpress?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create symlink to Wordpress public directory in Laravel folder. For example, `wp`:

```
/var
     /www
         /laravel
             /public
                 /wp #(symlink to -> /var/www/wordpress/public_html)
                 index.php
                 .htaccess
         /wordpress
             /public_html
                 index.php
                 .htaccess
```

And describe Laravel routes in .htaccess. Example of code of `/var/www/laravel/public/.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_FINISH} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Laravel

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.*\.php$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [E=FINISH:1,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(api/licenseplate)(\?.*|$) [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(api/calendar)(\?.*|$) [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(admin/settings)(\?.*|$) [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(admin/appointments)(\?.*|$) [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(appointment)(\?.*|$) [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(auth/login)(\?.*|$)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [E=FINISH:1,L]

    # Wordpress

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp/$1 [E=FINISH:1,L]

</IfModule>
```

Code of `/var/www/wordpress/public_html/.htaccess` (just copy of your wordpress .htaccess):

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: This answer assumes more than the question suggests, particularly that the user has much control for parent directories of `public_html`. It is also strange to have `/var/www/wordpress/public_html` and there is nothing telling Apache to look in `/var/www/laravel/public/.htaccess` for requests to `domain.com`.

Comment: Qevo, Web server must look into `/var/www/laravel/public/`. It is more safe solution. In this approach user cannot view nothing besides `/var/www/laravel/public/` and `/var/www/wordpress/public_html/`. Even if `.htaccess` files will be accidently deleted.

Comment: You are correct that requests must be confined to the `public` folder. My point is that your answer assumes that Apache has settings that point to this folder and this is not a reasonable assumption.

Comment: One upvote for the symlink solution, the same thing can be done to place a WP site besides a Symfony project, just replace the symlink to the Laravel public folder with one to the Symfony's web one.

Comment: Be careful with symlinks. I had a serious problems with them when working with git and different deployment scripts (python and ansistrano playbook).

Comment: @Rafal Kozlowski, I belive what adding `laravel/public/wp` into `.gitignore` at this case is good way.

Comment: @mnv it will help if You have 1 local environment and 1 production server to take care of. It becomes complicated, when You need to deploy solutions on several test servers, keep versions of prod deployment etc. I'm always trying to avoid using symlinks, and I have a feeling that this is a good practice. It is always better so separate different domains logic. I would suggest using real directories instead of symlinks. Of course a lot depends on the size of project and system complexity.

Answer (score 4):

### Server Structure

`.htaccess` files provide a way to make configuration changes on a per-directory basis. This means that you only need to direct the request to the directory that will have rules for how to best process the request. Thus you will leave the `.htaccess` files that came with both Laravel and WordPress in their directories. Just create another one for the parent directory that holds them both.

The below assumes that the full path of `public_html` is `/var/www/public_html`.

#### Folder Structure

```
/var/www/public_html/laravel
/var/www/public_html/wp
```

#### /var/www/public_html/.htaccess

```
# Limit Access To Laravel Public Folder
<Directory "/var/www/public_html/laravel">
    Order Deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/public_html/laravel/public">
    Allow from all
</Directory>

# Rewrite Requests
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Do Not Rewrite Directory And File Requests
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [L]

    # Rewrite Laravel Routes
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} api/licenseplate [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} api/calendar [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} admin/settings [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} admin/appointments [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} appointment [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} auth/login
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ laravel/public/$1 [L]

    # Rewrite To WordPress For Everything Else
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ wp/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

### Application Settings

Both Laravel and WordPress have ways to generate links to their assets (images, CSS, JavaScript).

WordPress is built to easily allow for installation to a sub-directory so you only need to change the WordPress Address and Site Address on the [General Settings Screen](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_General_Screen).

Laravel assumes that it is installed to the top directory. The [`asset()` helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-asset) is used to generate paths to asset files. So you will need to override the default function with one of your own. Here is how:

#### Create `app/helpers.php` with these contents

```
/**
 * Generate an asset path for the application
 * with the installation sub-directory 
 * prepended to the path.
 *
 * @param  string  $path
 * @param  bool    $secure
 * @return string
 */
function asset($path, $secure = null)
{
    $path = ltrim($path, '/');
    $dir = basename(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/public';
    $url = app('url')->asset($path, $secure);
    return str_replace($path, $dir . '/' . $path, $url);
}
```

#### Add `app/helpers.php` to the autoload process by editing `composer.json`

```
"autoload": {    
    //...
    "files": [
        "app/helpers.php"
    ]
},
```

#### If you have command line access, update PHP composer

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach that I took when encountered a similar situation. Install your `wordpress` in `public_html` directory and preferably place your `laravel application` with the WP directory:

```
wp-admin/  
wp-content/  
wp-includes/  
... other wordpress files ...
app/ <-- laravel application  
     |-> app/
     |-> bootstrap/
     |-> config/
     |-> public/
     |-> ... other laravel files and directories ...
```

> Now to get the `WordPress functions` available within your `Laravel
>   application`, include `wp-load.php` within your `Laravel` installation
>   and then you can use the `enqueueing functions` from `WordPress` to
>   load the assets you need.

Best approach is to follow the Laravel Service Provider Architecture. Write a service provider for including the `wp-load.php` and use the `boot function` to load assets:

```
// app/Providers/WordPressServiceProvider.php

class WordPressServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    protected $bootstrapFilePath = '../../wp-load.php'; // Adjust ur path

    public function boot() {
        // Load assets
        wp_enqueue_style('app', '/app/public/app.css'); // Adjust ur path
    }

    public function register() {
        // Load wordpress bootstrap file
        if(File::exists($this->bootstrapFilePath)) {
            require_once $this->bootstrapFilePath;
        } else throw new \RuntimeException('WordPress Bootstrap file not found!');
    }

}
```

And add the service provider to your laravel app config, `config/app.php:`

```
 /* ... */
   'providers' => [
        // ...

        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        // ...
        App\Providers\WordPressServiceProvider::class,
```

Now we have access to our WordPress functions within Laravel and can alter laravel `views` to something like:

```
{!! get_header() !!}
        <div class="container">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="title">Laravel 5</div>
                <div class="quote">{{ Inspiring::quote() }}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
{!! get_footer() !!}
```

Your wordpress site should be accessible at `www.urdomain.com` and laravel app under url  `www.urdomain.com/app/appointment` or adjust you `.htaccess` if you wish a different URL pattern.  Hope this help.

Comment: This is interesting but odds are that there are different user bases for the WordPress and Laravel development. Still, an intriguing way to establish frontend consistency between the two applications.

Comment: @Qevo, as most of the WP functions will now be available within Laravel App, we can easily adjust the behaviour of user authentication & management to use the same user base. If u see, In fact it will more difficult in case of the accepted answer.

Comment: To clarify, I meant different users who would be developing either Laravel or WordPress. You make a very good point that I did not consider about authentication between apps. I can only assume that this is not needed at this time.

Comment: I see, but I believe a true integration of two frameworks is where both can interact seamlessly without exposing anything to the end users. Otherwise, i dont think there is a need of any such hassles. It would be just a matter of setting up symlinks & or few redirects.

Comment: I think OP is not concerned about frontend & or UX consistency :{