# Laravel with Wordpress blog (with WP API)

Tags: wordpress, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5

My progect structure

```
/root_dir
  /app
  /bootstrap
  ...
  /public
    index.php
      .htaccess
    /wp            #wordpress installation here
      /wp-admin
      /wp-content
      /wp-includes
      index.php
      .htaccess
      ...
```

So what I want to acomplish is to have Laravel project with views, API etc

And I need wordpress only for one route `domain.com/blog` where I'll have *separate default WP blog that **doesn't** integrate or interact with my Laravel app in any way*

My `/public/.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
  </IfModule>

  RewriteEngine On

  # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

  # Handle Front Controller...

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(blog) #ADDED ONLY THIS MAGIC LINE

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

  # Handle Authorization Header
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
  RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

And my /public/blog/.htaccess is WP default

And it works like a charm!

My lara routes are fine... API routes - good... WP blog - great...

BUT

Now I want to call WP API, e.g. `domain.com/blog/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`

And all I see is Laravel's "NOT FOUND" page

Please help!

I have a strong feeling it can be solved with .htacess 'magic' but unfortunately I'm noob in that...

---

P.S. Found a similar question here [Laravel project next to Wordpress project (in public_html folder)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38716585/laravel-project-next-to-wordpress-project-in-public-html-folder)
But I need vice versa solution

Comment: http://pict.uws.ac.uk/~davison/sss/wp/wp-content/uploads/LaravelOnLAMP.pdf there is a section about Wordpress next to Laravel 5.4

Comment: why don't you use sub domain for wordpress ?
for example blog.example.com
so you can have separate projects and separate site configurations for web server.

Comment: @LeszekRepie Yes and all that is written there is already working in my app. The main problem: I can't call WP API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holy cow!

The solution was to navigate to dashboard/settings/permalinks and change option from 'plain' to any other!

Found the answer here https://wordpress.org/support/topic/rest-api-in-wp-4-7/#post-8620246

> You need to be using pretty permalinks to access /wp-json/. If you’re not, you can instead use ?rest_route=/ to get the index and ?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts (e.g.) for specific routes.

Answer (score 1):

you can proxy pass the address http://example.com/blog to some other address,
for example using nginx :

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name blog.example.com;

    location / {
        root /var/www/wordpress;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

 }





server {
    listen  80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        root /var/www/laravel;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }


    location /blog/ {

       proxy_pass http://blog.example.com/;
    }
 }
```

This is a simple and also clean way, and also you don't need to change even one line of code to have laravel and wordpress aside each other.

Comment: Op is using `.htaccess` files, which are not supported by Nginx, but you've provide an nginx configuration. Your suggestion won't work on OP's server.

Comment: And what if I have no access to apache/nginx configuration on my hosting? Any thoughts?

Comment: check if mod your server mod_proxy is installed with this command :
apache2ctl -M
if you have shell access and if you don't use this php function to get list of installed modules : 
apache_get_modules
and if it's installed use this tutorial 
https://devops.profitbricks.com/tutorials/configure-apache-as-a-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-on-ubuntu/

Comment: @mhndev Your answer is good but won't help if I can't configure nginx and i have no sudo user

But I upvoted your answer in case it might help someone